# How to not trigger 'complete' handler when error occurred in concatMap?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

When dealing with concatMap, how can I abort the execution of observables further down the line *and* prevent calling the completion handler?
Here is a simple example.

```js
of(...[1, 2, 3]).pipe(
  concatMap(t => of(t)),
  map(n => {
    console.log(n);
    if (n === 2) {
      throw new Error('OK, fail here');
    }
  }),
  catchError((e, c) => of(console.log('Caught ' + e)))
)
  .subscribe(
    {
      complete: () => console.log('Complete should not be triggered in an error case, but here it is'),
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log('I did never trigger, thats ok!');
      }
    });
```

A source observable emits 1,2,3 which is piped into concatMap.
There are two possible scenarios: All three observables are emitted without error in this case complete handler should be triggered. Or the other case depicted here: Somewhere down the line there is an error like when n === 2. ConcatMap stops executing the next observable which is *perfect* but it still triggers the completion handler, which is undesired.

## Actual result

```
1
2
Caught Error: OK, fail here
Complete should not be triggered in an error case, but here it is
```

## Desired result

```
1
2
Caught Error: OK, fail here
```

Any hints? My previous attempt was to throw in the next handler but that turned out to be really bad :/ as it triggered a `hostReportError`

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
since I was able to answer all the other fun questions regarding RxJS by myself, here we go :)

Remember: `catchError` replaces the faulted observable by some other observable. If `catchError` would therefore return an observable via `throwError` it would halt the execution and even better, it would trigger the error handler that was idle before.

```js
    of(...[1, 2, 3]).pipe(
      concatMap(t => of(t)),
      map(n => {
        console.log(n);
        if (n === 2) {
          throw new Error('OK, fail here');
        }
      }),
      catchError((e, c) => throwError(e)) // This line has changed
    )
      .subscribe(
        {
          complete: () => console.log('Complete should not be triggered in an error case, but here it is'),
          error: (err: any) => {
            console.log('Now I have something to do, yay!');
          }
        });
```

Comment: You don't need the `catchError` operator at all here. Every operator is effectively surrounded by a try-catch block and turns a stream into an errored stream if an exception is thrown. `throw new Error('OK, fail here');` will already trigger your `error` callback in your subscription. Which if you think about it, must work since it's the same callback the `catchError` operator hooks into.